# Adding two pseudocolor plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, plot

I have two pseudocolor plot, one going from red (1) to white (0) to blue (-1) and one going from green (1) to white (0).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((16,16))
b = 2*np.random.random((16,16)) - 1

plt.pcolor(a, vmax =1.0, vmin = 0.0, cmap = 'bwr')
plt.savefig("bwr.png")
plt.pcolor(b, vmax =1.0, vmin = -1.0, cmap = 'Greens')
plt.savefig("Greens.png")
```

I want to be able to add them to get one image where if a is 1 and b is 1, I get yellow and if a is 1 and b is -1, I get cyan. If both are zero then I should get white. I tried adding the pcolors plot using opencv2:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

r = cv2.imread('bwr.png')
mi = cv2.imread('Greens.png')
combo = cv2.addWeighted(r, 0.55, mi, 0.55, 0.2)

cv2.imwrite('combo.png',combo)
cv2.imshow('combo',combo)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But it's not producing the desired output:

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The color maps are set up to do R -> R^3 mapping, you want to do R^2 -> R^3 mapping.  There has been some talk of adding 2D color maps to mpl, but it has not happened yet.  Your best bet is to implement that for your case and then throw an RGB (`(n, m, 3)` shaped) array at `imshow`